# Zipline Bundle yesterday's data

Tags: python, python-3.5, quantitative-finance, zipline

I'm creating a custom basic yahoo bundle by adding the following to extenstion.py in the $ZIPLINE_ROOT directory:

```
equities = {
    'AAPL',
    'QQQ',
}
register(
    'test-bundle',  # name this whatever you like
    yahoo_equities(equities),
)
```

and when i run the bundle ingest everything is fine.

```
zipline ingest -b test-bundle

zipline bundles
```

produces the output (i just ran it a second ago)

```
test-bundle 2016-12-10 20:13:11.014192
```

great, everything is working as expected.

when i run zipline with some basic strategy for 2 weeks:

```
 zipline run -f ./test_algo.py --start 2016-12-01 --end 2016-12-9 -o output.pickle --bundle test-bundle
```

it runs, until it gets to Thursdays (12/08/2016) date:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1325, in _has_valid_type error()
 File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1320, in error (key, self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
  KeyError: 'the label [2016-12-08 00:00:00+00:00] is not in the [index]'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  .... zipline stack trace
```

but if i run it:

```
 zipline run -f ./test_algo.py --start 2016-12-01 --end 2016-12-7 -o output.pickle --bundle test-bundle
```

Then i get the expected successful output:

```
 [2016-12-10 20:17:11.519059] INFO: Performance: Simulated 5 trading days out of 5.
 [2016-12-10 20:17:11.519495] INFO: Performance: first open: 2016-12-01 14:31:00+00:00
 [2016-12-10 20:17:11.519770] INFO: Performance: last close: 2016-12-07 21:00:00+00:00
```

Any idea why my bundles are downloading to T-2 data.  I would expect to see 12/8 and 12/9's data, the markets were open it was normal days and i see data in yahoo finance for those days.

Thanks -

Answer (score 1):

This is because the benchmark returns are not available, and only available from a T-2 basis, including the trading day.  (IE: if you run it on a monday morning then thursday's data will be available and you can run a simulation until friday)  if you run it on a saturday / sunday the last possible day for the benchmark is wednesday, and the latest simulation day is thursday.

possible solutions:

1. Modify Zipline to be able to turn the benchmark off
2. Modify Zipline to use any ticker as the benchmark (and just the default stock indicies) from a bundle

current workaround:

modify:   ./zipline/gens/tradesimulation.py

and set:

```
 def handle_benchmark(date, benchmark_source=self.benchmark_source):
     algo.perf_tracker.all_benchmark_returns[date] = 1
```

this way it doesn't check if there is data, and just always returns 1 for a benchmark